# Pass multi argument function pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got the following error on executing the below code:

> None of [Index(['df.a', 'df.b', 'df.c', 'df.d',\n       'df.e',
>   'df.f'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]

I need help to resolve this.

```
def myfun(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    a, b, c, d, e, f
    z1 = 'r'
    z2= 'l'
    x = modulefunc(z1,a,b,c,abs(d),e,z2,f)
    return x

df.loc[:,('x')] = df[['df.a', 'df.b', 'df.c','df.d','df.e','df.f']].apply(myfun, axis=1)
```

Comment: Remove the df. in the columns of df[['df.a', 'df.b', 'df.c','df.d','df.e','df.f']]. So make it df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']].

Comment: TypeError: ("myfunc() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', and 'f'", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: getting the above type error.(thanks for the solution)

Answer (score 0):

Change to this. Assume `modulefunc` returns a scalar, otherwise you will get errors on assigning back.

```
def myfun(row):
    a, b, c, d, e, f = row
    z1 = 'r'
    z2= 'l'
    x = modulefunc(z1,a,b,c,abs(d),e,z2,f)
    return x

df['x'] = df[['a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f']].apply(myfun, axis=1)
```